# Error when trying to setting up the CKAN filestore with local storage: Permission Denied

Tags: python, ckan

I set up the local file storage according to these steps

http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/filestore.html

1. Create location

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/ckan/default
   ```

   I confirm the location exists and is in the right location
2. I uncomment the lines

   ```
   ofs.impl = pairtree
   ofs.storage_dir = /var/lib/ckan/default
   ```

   I confirmed I have pairtree and argparse installed
3. I am using jetty as the web server not Apache so I do

   ```
   sudo chown jetty /var/lib/ckan/default
   sudo chmod u+rwx /var/lib/ckan/default
   sudo service jetty restart
   ```
4. Then I run this command to start my site

   ```
   paster serve /etc/ckan/default/development.ini
   ```

I then get this stack trace back, I am doing all of these commands inside my virtual environment

```
2013-12-04 17:39:46,369 WARNI [ckan.lib.uploader] Please use config option ckan.storage_path instaed of
                     ofs.storage_path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/paster", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PasteScript==1.7.5', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 104, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 143, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 238, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/serve.py", line 284, in command
    relative_to=base, global_conf=vars)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/serve.py", line 321, in loadapp
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 272, in loadobj
    return context.create()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 710, in create
    return self.object_type.invoke(self)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 146, in invoke
    return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/util.py", line 56, in fix_call
    val = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware.py", line 156, in make_app
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/ckan/default/storage'
```

Comment: the answer was to change the owner permission to the owner permission of the paste site package folder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Permission denied: '/var/lib/ckan/default/storage'

It looks like you don't have permission to read and write to this directory. Try running these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /var/lib/ckan/default
sudo chmod -R u+rwx /var/lib/ckan/default
```

Answer (score 0):

For those stumbling on this years later...

I ran into this when trying to setup datastore and run the `paster --plugin=ckan datastore set-permissions -c /etc/ckan/default/production.ini` command.

I had already [setup FileStore as per the docs](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/filestore.html#setup-file-uploads). What I ended up having to do was upload a resource in the web UI then re-run the command above and the error no longer appeared and the output worked as expected. After uploading a resource the `/var/lib/ckan/default/resources` and `/var/lib/ckan/default/storage` directories were created with the proper permissions and the paster command didn't need to try and create them (or so I'm assuming).

Here's some additional resources in case you have a slightly different issue that's causing this error:

- https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/3676
- https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/4548
- https://lists.okfn.org/pipermail/ckan-dev/2018-November/022974.html

Answer (score 0):

Sample 500 error in ckan 2.9

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/ckan/default/webassets/.webassets-cache'
```

To remove the permission error;

Set the permission and ownership. The [docs on filestore](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/maintaining/filestore.html) misses out on the ownership and recursive mode

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/lib/ckan/default
sudo chmod u+rwx -R /var/lib/ckan/default
```

Finally restart your server:

```
sudo supervisorctl restart ckan-uwsgi:*
```